# Switch in TypeScript does not narrow actions

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a problem using an union type in a switch statement like this:

```
function createApiTypes(value: string) {
  return {
    REQUEST: `${value}__REQUEST` as const,
    SUCCESS: `${value}__SUCCESS` as const,
    ERROR: `${value}__ERROR` as const,
  };
}

const GET_FRUITS = createApiTypes('GET_FRUITS')

type Actions = {type: typeof GET_FRUITS.SUCCESS, payload: []} | {type: typeof GET_FRUITS.ERROR, payload: string} | {type: typeof GET_FRUITS.REQUEST}

function reducer(action: Actions) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_FRUITS.SUCCESS: {
            console.log(action.payload) // Error: Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'Actions'.
            break;
        }
        case GET_FRUITS.ERROR: {
            console.log(action.payload) // Error: Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'Actions'.
            break;
        }
        case GET_FRUITS.REQUEST: {
            console.log(action)
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQQQA4wAqAnnmgM4AUAbhgDYhoBci5UKMYA5gJSIDeAKESJ0UECiRCRIgEoBRAIoBVeQGVCLAAYASfrQZoAvgH0TClesJbEGcsgRsANMJlrlAYQ-q12vQcZTE3cvHxs7BzBnVxF5WVkAeVk-fXpAszjE2XD7CEcoFxEjAG5BI0FBPKioRABxeUITADFZZQBJQjVEAF5kdCxcAhIyKgByesaW9s7RngqoUjREHGh4KJ6BBbIWLbQ4YDqG5taOtQA6EO81NSdEPAxiOjgMABMWAG0AXSNEAB9NxY7Rb7Q6TE6dM6ZJK3e6PZ5vVjsThcH7-fi7IFkEETY7Tc4WVQacqCUCQWAIURoF4gCBoFCUDCrBAsFbkqJ8aQycgAdxgUAgAAtEAymWAzrsOTEZCIIHYljipqcLp4rr4BFLpdKquQ4HQ0GcnlwRWyzrCnq8+AB6S2IeQoFBwFAsAAKDrIKAWiFGZvho0QLzgFEQYDgNTQAA8YGxEBTdl7WWtyKMzhrNSIAEb9ADWpTTRVTMrloNxSqhyXVec12t1+sNxrWpoe5peVptdodTsQrrg7s93qbvv9gfsIbDkejscW8dFSZTlelmcwOYLiHKldl5HlR0VEIJVhYnPnkR1eoNcCNjLZcyPGezubza5k5XKQA)

If I change `action.type` to a string the switch works without any problem, but if I generate the keys using the function `createApiTypes` it does not work.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the keys in `GET_FRUITS` are inferred as `` `${string}__REQUEST` `` and likewise, rather than `'GET_FRUITS__REQUEST'` as you would need.

The solution is really straightforward: change the signature of your `createApiTypes` function so that `value` has a generic type instead. Then Typescript will infer a string literal type for `value`, and exact types for the keys of `GET_FRUITS`, and then narrowing works exactly as you'd expect.

```
function createApiTypes<T extends string>(value: T) {
  return {
    REQUEST: `${value}__REQUEST` as const,
    SUCCESS: `${value}__SUCCESS` as const,
    ERROR: `${value}__ERROR` as const,
  };
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-UGQ7zw5GB9HY-HWEmU-R0ynM4dsyq8wX2zpS5gKzWVG0q3WG6jaW96V4pBLd1au-a4I6BaK9ruS+XK0WTzo2m0gA)

Answer (score 0):

This will works :)

```
function createApiTypes<T extends string>(value: T) {
  return {
    REQUEST: `${value}__REQUEST` as `${T}__REQUEST`,
    SUCCESS: `${value}__SUCCESS` as `${T}__SUCCESS`,
    ERROR: `${value}__ERROR` as `${T}__ERROR`,
  };
}
```

[see more](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)